# My WSO2 Integration Studio flows come out it to production through Enterpise Integrator 7.1.0 but I have problem to import one of my projects

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I use Integration Studio 8.0 and Enterprise Integrator 7.1.0 and I have 2 projects flows in WSO2 Integration Studio and was try import to WSO2 Enterprise Integrator environment for take them to production.

I have 2 projects, the first project is "Hello World" based the which is an API that proportions an Web Service that show the string "Hello User" in JSON output format, the POM.XML code the which I export in format ".CAR" for import it toEnterprise Integrator environment is the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>wso2.sampleHelloWorld</groupId>
    <artifactId>HolaMundo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>HM</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>carbon/application</packaging>
  <name>HM</name>
  <description>HM</description>
  <properties>
    <wso2.sampleHelloWorld.metadata_._HelloWorld_swagger>capp/EnterpriseServiceBus</wso2.sampleHelloWorld.metadata_._HelloWorld_swagger>
    <wso2.sampleHelloWorld.api_._HelloWorld>capp/EnterpriseServiceBus</wso2.sampleHelloWorld.api_._HelloWorld>
    <wso2.sampleHelloWorld.metadata_._HelloWorld_metadata>capp/EnterpriseServiceBus</wso2.sampleHelloWorld.metadata_._HelloWorld_metadata>
    <artifact.types>jaggery/app=zip,synapse/priority-executor=xml,synapse/inbound-endpoint=xml,service/rule=aar,synapse/message-store=xml,event/stream=json,service/meta=xml,datasource/datasource=xml,synapse/proxy-service=xml,bpel/workflow=zip,synapse/sequence=xml,synapse/endpointTemplate=xml,carbon/application=car,wso2/gadget=dar,synapse/api=xml,synapse/event-source=xml,synapse/message-processors=xml,event/receiver=xml,lib/dataservice/validator=jar,synapse/template=xml,synapse/endpoint=xml,lib/carbon/ui=jar,lib/synapse/mediator=jar,synapse/metadata=yaml,event/publisher=xml,synapse/local-entry=xml,synapse/task=xml,webapp/jaxws=war,registry/resource=zip,synapse/configuration=xml,service/axis2=aar,synapse/lib=zip,synapse/sequenceTemplate=xml,event/execution-plan=siddhiql,service/dataservice=dbs,web/application=war,lib/library/bundle=jar</artifact.types>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>wso2.sampleHelloWorld.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>xml</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>wso2.sampleHelloWorld.metadata</groupId>
      <artifactId>HelloWorld_metadata</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>yaml</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>wso2.sampleHelloWorld.metadata</groupId>
      <artifactId>HelloWorld_swagger</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>yaml</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-maven2-repository-1</id>
      <url>https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-nexus-repository-1</id>
      <url>https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-maven2-repository-1</id>
      <url>https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-nexus-repository-1</id>
      <url>https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <buildcommands />
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.distribution.project.nature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-car-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.34</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>car</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>car</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration />
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-car-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <carbonServers>
            <CarbonServer>
              <trustStorePath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</trustStorePath>
              <trustStorePassword>wso2carbon</trustStorePassword>
              <trustStoreType>JKS</trustStoreType>
              <serverUrl>https://localhost:9443</serverUrl>
              <userName>admin</userName>
              <password>admin</password>
              <operation>deploy</operation>
            </CarbonServer>
          </carbonServers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

apps-fileview.texmex_20230525.01_p2
HM.xml
Mostrando HM.xml
```

I generate de CAR file to import in Enterprise Integrator environment doing righ click on my project  and then "New -> Composite Exporter -> Click on my Configs folder checkbox" and set  a Module Name and i go clic in finish.

Then i copy my generated CAR file to the next directory:

```
/WSO2/wso2ei/7.1.0/micro-integrator/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps
```

Then after execute and start my Enterprise Integrator services, i was entry to API sections of my dashboard for check that my API is avaible, i verified this at see my HelloWorld api in the cell below API NAME row, the next is a capture to this:
[image]

And when test mi API with POSTMAN i can doi correctly, the evidence is the next:
[image]

Ok, well, but also have another API that execute a stored procedure from MySQL but when I do the previous steps for import mi CAR file to the Enterprise Integrator environment to implements in production my stored procedure API doesn't appear in the API cells when be supposed that should appear below the HelloWorld API but not! Unfortunately I can't visualize.

Does anyone know why I can't show my stored procedure API in my Enterprise Integrator dashboard? The `POM.XML` file that I use to export my CAR file is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>wso2.sampleRESTDataService</groupId>
    <artifactId>StoredProcedure</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>wso2.sampleRESTDataService</groupId>
  <artifactId>StoredProcedureCompositeExporter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>carbon/application</packaging>
  <name>StoredProcedureCompositeExporter</name>
  <description>StoredProcedureCompositeExporter</description>
  <properties>
    <com.example.dataservice_._RESTDataService>capp/DataServicesServer</com.example.dataservice_._RESTDataService>
    <artifact.types>jaggery/app=zip,synapse/priority-executor=xml,synapse/inbound-endpoint=xml,service/rule=aar,synapse/message-store=xml,event/stream=json,service/meta=xml,datasource/datasource=xml,synapse/proxy-service=xml,bpel/workflow=zip,synapse/sequence=xml,synapse/endpointTemplate=xml,carbon/application=car,wso2/gadget=dar,synapse/api=xml,synapse/event-source=xml,synapse/message-processors=xml,event/receiver=xml,lib/dataservice/validator=jar,synapse/template=xml,synapse/endpoint=xml,lib/carbon/ui=jar,lib/synapse/mediator=jar,synapse/metadata=yaml,event/publisher=xml,synapse/local-entry=xml,synapse/task=xml,webapp/jaxws=war,registry/resource=zip,synapse/configuration=xml,service/axis2=aar,synapse/lib=zip,synapse/sequenceTemplate=xml,event/execution-plan=siddhiql,service/dataservice=dbs,web/application=war,lib/library/bundle=jar</artifact.types>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.dataservice</groupId>
      <artifactId>RESTDataService</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <type>dbs</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-maven2-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-nexus-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-maven2-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-nexus-repository-1</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <buildcommands />
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.distribution.project.nature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-car-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.34</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>car</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>car</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration />
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-car-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <carbonServers>
            <CarbonServer>
              <trustStorePath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</trustStorePath>
              <trustStorePassword>wso2carbon</trustStorePassword>
              <trustStoreType>JKS</trustStoreType>
              <serverUrl>https://localhost:9443</serverUrl>
              <userName>admin</userName>
              <password>admin</password>
              <operation>deploy</operation>
            </CarbonServer>
          </carbonServers>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

apps-fileview.texmex_20230525.01_p2
SP.xml
Mostrando SP.xml
```

The steps for put my HelloWorld CAR file in the Enterprise Integrator enviroment are the same that i followed to put my Stored Procedure in Enterprise Integrator but mi Stored Procedure dont be can showed in my APIs section in the Dashboard, anyone believe known the causes for the which i can show my API correctly?? i believe that is relationed with my POM.XML file  but maybe be something else.

In my Integration Studio IDE i can run the twos API correctly, the HelloWorld and my Procedured Store but in Enterprise Integrator only can run my Hello World API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the repository/logs/wso2carbon.log file to make sure the car file got deployed correctly?
Some possible scenarios are if the DB is unreachable or the required JDBC libraries are not available, it will not get deployed.

Comment: oks, also anyone mentioned to me i must check the "datasource" directory, you know where is???

Comment: You can configure data sources within tha capp, or else you can add common data sources in the conf/deployment.toml file